# ASP.NET MVC4 routing ignored for static files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application .NET4 in which a routing exists for content files, which are served from a resource inside a class library.
Routing is configured as follows

```
routes.MapRoute("Resources", "Default{Content}/{*contentpath}", new {controller = "Resource", action="GetResource"});
```

So if there is a request **DefaultMvcScripts/test.js**, the **GetResource** method will be called.

However, when converted to MVC4 ,.NET4.5 this doesn't work anymore, GetResource is not called anymore, it bypasses routing even if I put

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

For a request **DefaultMvcScript/test** (without extension), routing is not ignored (I can see GetResource being called).

Can I have the old behaviour back, so that even if I specify an extension, routing is honoured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, adding this to the web.config restores previous behaviour:

```
<modules>
   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
   <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

The preCondition="" seems to be the trick.

Source: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the last step - you need to configure your app so that the handler pipeline pays attention to requests for static files.

In they system.webserver section of the web config you need to add a handler for the static files you want to serve. You need to use the TransferRequestHandler

```
<add name="staticHandler" path="*.js" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersion4.0"/>
```

See Jon Galloway's article for a complete description
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works